# Seeking a RegExp to replace every seventh comma by \n

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a list that looks like this:

```
11, 11, 12, 12, "abc", 3, 1, 25, 25, 30, 30, "def", 1, 1, ......
```

and I want to change it so it looks like this:

```
11, 11, 11, 11, "abc", 3, 1
25, 25, 30, 30, "def", 1, 1
....
```

So I want to replace every seventh comma by \n.

I tried using sed for this but can't get it to work. Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed -e -r 's/(([^,]+,){6}[^,]+), /\1\n/g'
```

Comment: This is what I get
sed: -e expression #1, char 29: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: I added the`-e` flag... try that. If that fails, please type here exactly what you are entering (if different from the command in my answer). You do realise that you must pass sed some input right? for example `cat myfile | sed ...` or you can give it a file: `sed -e 's/.../.../g' myfile`

Comment: I already added that -e before. Doesn't work with or without.. I do copy & paste your code exactly and use it with a piped cat, doesn't work. The problem seems to be, it does not get the \1 part, don't know why...

Comment: I found the solution. To work with \1 you need -r. now it works, Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: There is one thing I don't quite understand in that expression: wouldn't [^,]+ cover the entire file already? + means 1 or more I think, but how does sed know I only want one and not the entire file?

Comment: @user3196122 `[^,]` means "any character except a comma". That's why it doesn't consume past commas.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/,\s*/\n/7;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
(([^,]+, ?){7})
```

And replace with `$1\n`.

Unsure of the `sed` syntax, but here's the expression to play around with: http://regex101.com/r/oH8oK3

Comment: Won't that preserve the 7th comma?

Comment: @Bohemian yeah, it will. Yours wins :)

Comment: Also with sed, back references are `\1` not `$1` (why can't "they" be consistent!?)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/, */\^J/7'
# or
sed 's/,[[:blank:]]*/\^J/7'
```

Also remove the trailing space (or blank like tab also) [option -posix with GNU sed]